# Converting 1d array to 2d array by ascending order of numbers

Tags: c#

I want to create a 2D array such that value of matrix position `[m,n` is decided by the numbers in `arr1`.

For example. if the *numbers* in arr1 are increasing i.e. `arr1[i] <= arr1[i+1]`,  `1` must appear in respective column.

i.e. value at cinema `[0,0]` is `1` because `1<4`. similarly value at `cinema[0,3]` is also `1` because `4<6` and so on

If the next value is smaller (i.e. `arr1[i] > arr1[i+1]` i.e `6>2`) then the *row* must be change after assigning value

i.e. `cinema[0,5] = 1` followed by increment in row number `m++` so that next value gets placed in next row.

i.e. next iteration would be `cinema[1,1] = 1` and so on.

In the end after assasing all the values in `cinema[m,n]` resulted matrix should appear as shown in the rows below.

```
row 1 {10010100}
row 2 {01000001}
row 3 {11010000}
row 4 {00100100}
row 5 {01000000}
row 6 {10000001}
row 7 {00110010}
row 8 {00000000}
```

My current code

```
int[] arr1 = new int[] { 1, 4, 6, 2, 8, 1, 2, 4, 3, 6, 2, 1, 8, 3, 4, 7 };
  
int[,] cinema = new int[8, 8];
int m = 0;
int n = 0;
  
   for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
{
  
   if (arr1[i] <= arr1[i + 1])
   {
      n = arr1[i];
      //Console.Write(m);
      //Console.WriteLine(n);
      cinema[m, n] = 1;
  
   }
   else if (arr1[i] > arr1[i + 1])
   {
      n = arr1[i];
      //Console.Write(m);
      //Console.WriteLine(n);
      cinema[m, n] = 1;
      m++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Given `arr1[1] <= arr1[2]` why does row 1, index 1 == `0` ? when `4 < 6` shouldn't it be `1`?. In short, you have pasted this question multiple times. its just unclear to an outside observer (well it is to me). I think you may need to do a better job of explaining

Comment: *1 must appear in respective column". It seems from your examples that "respective column" is the column with index `arr1[i] - 1`